# How to change name in the visualization without changing the original name in Tableau

Tags: visualization, tableau-desktop

I am trying to change "Days in a month" to "No.of days in a month".

Actually, in the original data the column name is Days in a month.

I don't want to change the original name, but that name need to be change in VIZ..

Image link - https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCb8p.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCb8p.png

Please help me here.

Thanks in advance!

I have tried to use calculated field as 1.0

But its not giving the expected output.

Comment: did you try right clicking and editing the Alias ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.